# How to correctly combine scoreboard data?

Tags: unity, c#, ngui

I need a help with a scoreboard I am making. Here's the scoreboard I want to achieve:

[image]

I actually have 4 tables and each tables has its own scoreboard but for this question only one table matters.

Here's how I am creating this kind of scoreboard:

```
if (gametable_no == 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametable_history_list.Count; i++)
    {
        newString[0] += tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametable_history_list[i].r;
        newString[0] += ",";
    }
    string[] groupedString = newString[0].Split(',');

    foreach (string allchars in groupedString)
    {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        GameObject o = Instantiate(prefab_big_road[0]) as GameObject;
        o.transform.SetParent(pos_big_road[0]);
        o.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
        o.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(2.0f, -5.0f, 0f);
        o.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(o.transform.localPosition.x + x, 
            o.transform.localPosition.y + y, o.transform.localPosition.z);


        if (allchars.Contains(playerwinnopairboth))
        {
            o.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = "layout_player_bigline-01";
            NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);
        }
        if (allchars.Contains(bankerwinnopairboth))
        {
            o.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = "layout_banker_bigline-01";
            NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);
        }
        if (allchars.Contains(tienopairboth))
        {
            o.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = "layout_tie_bigline-01";
            NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);
        }
    }
}
```

The result I get with this code is this:

[image]

Here's what the data I use to generate the table looks like:

`Gametable 1 history : P  ,P  ,P  ,B   ,B P,P P,TBP`

So I need a way to know if the character is *changing* in the `gametable 1 history data`.

Here's the expected scoreboard output with the data above:

[image]

If the value is not changing like `P  ,P  ,P` then the position should only increment on the y-axis. If the next value is different like `B   ,` then it will move on the x-axis.

So, how would I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this

```
if (table.GetLength(0) < xIndex)
            {
                break;
            }

            if (previousValue.Equals(newPreviousValue) && yIndex < table.GetLength(1))
            {
                yIndex += 1;
                table[xIndex, yIndex] = previousValue;
            }
            else
            {
                xIndex += 1;
                yIndex = 0;
                table[xIndex, yIndex] = previousValue;
            }
            newPreviousValue = previousValue;
```

Thanks Tyyppi_77

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a C# user so the solution is pseudo-code, but it should be relatively trivially translated into actual compiling C# that uses the correct GUI positioning stuff that you need. I just use `x` and `y` to denote the position of the current score.

Anyways, the important bit here is to keep track of the previous item.

```
string previous = "";

string scores = history.split(",");

int x = 0, y = 0;

foreach (string score in scores)
{
    if (score == previous)
    {
        // Next row:
        y += 1
        addToTable(score, x, y);
    }
    else
    {
        // Next column: 
        x += 1
        y = 0
        previous = score;
        addToTable(score, x, y);
    }
}
```

The code simply iterates over all the scores, and keeps track of the previous score. If the items match, the row is incremented. Otherwise we move onto the next column and start from the top again.

Comment: sir could you please help me to implement it to my code

Comment: No, because I'm not familiar with your score board system, and because it's trivial enough for you to combine this with the code that you already have.